# MySQL insert specific values to column

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I want to create a table with two columns(name, hobby)
the hobby values should be from this list [football, baseball, art, gaming, basketball, golf]
how do I create a table like this?

Comment: You can use the `ENUM` datatype.

Comment: Please don't use the ENUM data type.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a foreign key relationship.  Often, this would use a numeric id column.  But you can also use string values, if you *really* prefer:

```
create table hobbies (
    hobby varchar(255) primary key
);

insert into hobbies (hobby)
    values ('football'), ('baseball'), . . . ;
```

Then you can define the `name`/`hobbies` table as:

```
create table name_hobbies (
     name varchar(255) not null,
     hobby varchar(255) not null,
     constraint fk_name_hobbies_hobby foreign key (hobby) references hobbies(hobby)
);
```

This makes it easy to add new hobbies or to add additional information about each hobby (say, how much money does it cost).

I should note that you can also use a `check` constraint now in MySQL:

```
create table name_hobbies (
     name varchar(255) not null,
     hobby varchar(255) not null,
     constraint chk_name_hobbies_hobby check (hobby in ('football', 'baseball', . . . ))
);
```